# Menu Block shows both languages

Tags: 7, routes, blocks, i18n-l10n

I'm using the i18n module for translating nodes and menu items.
I have a bunch of menu-items and am now trying to put that into the header with a menublock.

But unfortunately all menu-items in all languages appear instead of just the items in the current language and language-neutral.

Does anyone know how to fix that.

The only solution I have is to create a menu for every language.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay sorry ... it took some time, but I found the solution.

First I had the themed menu within the template, now I have the main menu direct as a block.

The solution was to edit the main menu and set the following option:

- *Translate and Localize. Menu items with language will allow
  translations. Menu items without language will be localized.*

That's it.